# Redirect from www to none-www not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-config

*The app is built on asp.net core 3.1 and react. They are on the same origin.*

In **web.config** redirection from `http` to `https` **working**.

In **web.config** redirection from `www.example.com` to `example.com` **not working**

```
        // Piece of my web.config
        <rules>
          <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
```

- In browser [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) goes in redirection loop and shows
  `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`
- In Postman the error is `Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop https://www.example.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule to redirect from www to none-www:

```
<rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Ty. Working when 1 rule instead of 2 rules. I guess the 2 rules go in loop on one each other. It is logical but I havent found such information. I guess the idea now is there is only 1 input and 1 action(redirect) for it?

Comment: Eventually later Ill redirect from none-www to www.  What would be the conditions and the action?

Comment: The execution order of url rules is from top to bottom. If you want to redirect from none-www to www, you can refer to this link: [https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www).